# Relationship between .cpp and .cu of a layer in CAFFE

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I found that a layer can be implemented in CPU  (.cpp) or GPU (.cu) version. For example, batch normalization layer has two source files:`batch_norm_layer.cpp` and `batch_norm_layer.cu`.

When I compile code, I select CUDA mode by uncommenting `USE_CUDNN := 1`. Then, when I use batch normalization layer, CAFFE will perform every thing in .cu file without getting any information from .cpp file. Am I right?

I asked it because I am not sure the correction of my CPU implementation, but I sure GPU implementation is correct. Hence, I don't know any wrong in CPU code can affect to my GPU code or not. Thanks

Comment: Please give me some information

Answer (score 2):

The `LayerSetup` is performed in the .cpp code, so you need to get this right. Otherwise, you are right (given you selected `solver_mode: GPU`), your .cu code should run for the forward and backward passes.

Comment: `Reshape` also runs in CPU.

Comment: Great. It is my expected. So, we need to implement correctly LayerSetup and Reshape function in CPU code. The Forward and Backward may be wrong and they do not affect to CUDA code. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you implemented the forward and backward passes in .cu, the .cpp versions will not affect these.